# GCC upgrade and shared libraries

Tags: macos, gcc, dynamic-linking

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks with command line tools installed, so I got clang-500.2.79. However, some software does not build with clang, hence I want to install GCC. So I got a question about GCC, specifically what will happen later when if I decide to upgrade GCC.

Suppose I install current version of GCC in /usr/gcc-4.8.2. Suppose I also use this gcc to build and install some software on my system that links against shared libraries in /usr/gcc-4.8.2/lib (in addition to system libraries in /usr/lib).

Suppose also I later decide to upgrade GCC to say version 4.9 and install it in /usr/gcc-4.9 and remove the old version in /usr/gcc-4.8.2.

Will the software that linked against shared libraries in /usr/gcc-4.8.2/lib continue to work i.e. will it magically (libtool?) find shared libraries in /usr/gcc-4.9 now? Or will everything I ever built with gcc-4.8.2 have to be recompiled after gcc upgrade?

Comment: The surest way to find out is to right now rename gcc-4.8.2 to something else and see if your executables still run.

Comment: If you just rename gcc-4.8.2 I would expect things to break. However, if GCC's libtool/linker has some kind of configuration that tells it where to look for dynamic libraries, then installing another version of gcc is fundamentally different than renaming.

Comment: Do you need to remove the old version? Just keep it around until you're sure you've recompiled everything...that's more or less what I do (though I keep older versions around for comparison purposes too).